# APScheduler running multiple times for the amount of gunicorn workers

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks, gunicorn, apscheduler

I have a django project with APScheduler built in it. I have proceeded to the production environment now so binded it with gunicorn and nginx in the proceess. Gunicorn has 3 workers. Problem is that gunicorn initiates the APScheduler for each worker and runs the scheduled job 3 times instead of running it for only once.

I have seen similar questions here it seems it is a common problem. Even the APScheduler original documentation acknowledges the problem and tells no way of fixing it.

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-share-a-single-job-store-among-one-or-more-worker-processes

I saw in other threads people recommended putting --preconfig in the settings. But I read that --preconfig initiates the workers with the current code and does not reload when there has been a change in the code.(See "when not to preload" in below link)

https://www.joelsleppy.com/blog/gunicorn-application-preloading/

I also saw someone recommended binding a TCP socket for the APScheduler. I did not understand it fully but basically it was trying to bind a socket each time APScheduler is initiated then the second and third worker hits that binded socket and throws a socketerror. Sort of

```
try: 
    "bind socket somehow" 
except socketerror:
    print("socket already exists")"
else:
    "run apscheduler module"
```

configuration. Does anyone know how to do it or know if that would actually work?

Another workaround I thought is simply removing the APScheduler and do it with cron function of the server. I am using Digital Ocean so I can simply delete the APScheduler and a cron function that will run the module instead. However, I do not want to go that way because that will make break the "unity" of the whole project and make it server dependable. Does anyone have any more ideas?

Schedule module:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from RENDER.views import dailypuzzlefunc

def start():
    scheduler=BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(dailypuzzlefunc,'cron', day="*",max_instances=2,id='dailyscheduler')
    scheduler.start()
```

In the app:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class DailypuzzleConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "DAILYPUZZLE"

    def ready(self):
        from SCHEDULER import dailypuzzleschedule
        dailypuzzleschedule.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
web: 
  python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; 
  gunicorn MasjidApp.wsgi --timeout 15 --preload

use --preload.
```

It's working well for me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've taken the liberty of editing your code for presentation on this site, however I'm not so familiar with django formatting. Would you take a look and edit for indentation/symbols and such?

Comment: Can you mention why this works. The answer is lacking necessary information.

Comment: --preload this means it's used first-time load ignoring 2nd-time load.

Answer (score 0):

--preload works like a charm.

This is from their official doc
[image]